# Max product in array of 2 elements

Tags: algorithm, divide-and-conquer, sub-array

Given an array of positive numbers I need to find the maximum of the expression `(j - i)*(b[j] + b[i])` where j and i are array indices. I tried using divide and conquer but in the merge step I could not find an efficient algorithm to combine the results of the left and right sub-arrays. The constraints on the length of the array is 1,000,000 (maximum array size), and time is 1 second. Your help is appreciated

Comment: Could you please mention the source so that I can try out some ideas there?

Comment: Are duplicate integers allowed in the array?

Comment: It's from https://codeforces.com/gym/102920/problem/L I tried your approach but got TLE, maybe you have a more optimized implementation

Comment: AMRO: TLE not WA?

Comment: [Is your question answered?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: Yeah I didn't really understand the solution but I found it on CS stack exchange

Answer (score 0):

Let us throw two pointers at the problem:

```
left = 0, right = length of array - 1
do{
    max_product = max(max_product, (right-left)*(array[left]+array[right]))
    if array[left] < array[right]:
        left++
    else
        right--
} while (left < right)
```

Time Complexity: O(size of array), Space Complexity: O(1)

---

*As Abinav pointed out, the greedy selection of max on the left won't work. So, below solution won't work.*

This is a dynamic programming based question. Maintain a `dp` array. `dp[index]` denotes index of `max(array[0]...array[index-1])`. So at every `index` you calculate

```
result = max(result, (index - dp[index]) * (array[dp[index]]+array[index])).
```

Time complexity: O(size of array),
Space complexity: O(size of array)

Try if it is possible to reduce space to `O(1)` as an exercise.

Comment: Why would you greedily pick the maximum value on the left?

Comment: @AbhinavMathur Right. Greedy pick won't work. I'll think more.

Comment: @AbhinavMathur How about now?

Comment: Can you prove that this is optimal? This might fail for ```[1,1000,1,1,1,1]```

Comment: Now we need to think something for equal values which pointer to move? We could try with choice of both one by one but time complexity will take a hit. I think we need to understand constraints of the problem if duplicates are allowed.

Comment: Yes, the constraints might be exploited in some way to solve this

Comment: Yeah, if duplicates are introduced, O(n) or 1,000,000 (maximum array size) with 1 second looks hard.

Answer (score 0):

Following the logic of Shridhar, i think that should works.

```
const arr = [1,3,5,2,3,6,89,2,13,45,67,7,8,9]

let left = 0 
let right = arr.length - 1 

let max = (left - right) * (arr[left] + arr[right])
right--
let ref = 0 
function algo(arr) {
        do {
                let sum = (left - right) * (arr[left] + arr[right])
                if (sum > max) max = sum 
                ref++
                if (ref % 2 === 0) right--
                else left++
                    
        } while(left < right)
            
        return max 
}

console.log(algo(arr))
```

Comment: The algorithm in the other answer isn't correct

Comment: that's right "if array[left] < array[right]:" is an err. But this code works.

Comment: How are you sure? Have you tested/submitted it?

Comment: change the arr[] with the numbers you like (negatif and positif), set one console.log(sum) and one console.log(max), you will see that the returned number is always the highest one

Comment: except this err, the logic and the code of Shridhar is good

Comment: How would it work for ```[1,1000,1,1,1,1]```?

Comment: it works (i checked it already). But note that i just took out the first "left++" (this one was a mistake :()

Comment: `let max = (left - right) * (arr[left] + arr[right])` I guess it should be `let max = (right - left) * (arr[left] + arr[right])`. That said, I doubt it can work in all cases

Comment: @Jerome can you prove that this is optimal? Because it is making a blind decision without any knowledge of further elements. Kind of like running binary search on an unsorted array

Comment: @Damien the `let max = (left - right) * (arr[left] + arr[right])` is following the expression `(j - i)*(a[j] + a[i])` which we evaluate. So it's correct.

Comment: @Abhinav you are right, it works like it, but the logic is wrong. So right now the algorithm is wrong or incomplete. Maybe sort it fix it (i will check later), but sorting an array is ressouce consuming as it re-index the full array.

Comment: @Abhinav, without sorting the array first (which will change the array indexation, so change the datas...), i don't see any optimised solution .....  (should have one of course, but i don t know....). But this algorithm i proposed is definatly wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding `(j - i) * (b[j] + b[i])`, we get:

```
j*b_j + j*b_i - i*b_j - i*b_i
```

which we can rewrite as the constant and vector dot product,

```
j*b_j + (j, -b_j, -1) ⋅ (b_i, i, i*b_i)
```

and then -- assuming all elements previous to the `j`th have been seen -- look for:

```
j*b_j + max((j, -b_j, -1) ⋅ (b_i, i, i*b_i))
  where i < j
```

Maximising the vector dot product can be achieved in log time with convex hull and farthest point query, although implementation is not trivial.